# Is there a way to use mv command to move directory in S3 bucket with aws-sdk ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems

I am using aws-sdk v1 ruby gem. I want to move a directory to another one in one  S3 bucket.

I read the document of v1, but didn't find that method. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `move` method is not available in any of the AWS SDKs. For one, I have checked the Ruby and PHP SDK.

However, there is a [mv](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html) command in the [AWS-CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) tool which you can use to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Very important information!

Comment: Oh my god Noman you are so awesome! How can someone be this genius. I am your biggest fannnn.. thankyouuu!!!!